# linq to excel not ignoring blank sheet

Tags: c#, linq-to-excel

I have been using linq to excel on one of my projects and it works great !

Its throwing a System.Data.DataException if a sheet in my excel file is blank.This is how i am querying

```
     var excelInfo = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelFileName);
     var excelRecords = from c in excelInfo.Worksheet<myclass>(sheetname) where c.Result!=null select c;
```

Also tried this based on a suggestion

```
  from c in excelInfo.Worksheet<myclass>(sheetname) where c.Result!=null || c.Result!="" select c
```

I am getting an error on the 2nd line if the sheet is blank.
If i add an header, obviously it works. So how do i check whether the sheet is blank or not before calling that line of code. Or is there any option within linqtoexcel that i am missing to ignore blank sheets?

Thanks!

Comment: Try also checking that c.Result is not an empty string.

Comment: unfortunately does not work..I tried that ...

Comment: Post your code with the way you tried it.

Comment: from c in excelInfo.Worksheet<myclass>(sheetname) where c.Result!=null || c.Result!=""  select c

Comment: You need an AND, not an OR.

Comment: i am not sure how you can have an AND. A string can either be null or empty but cannot be both !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67061/discussion-between-dugas-and-cableload).

Answer (score 0):

Try also excluding when the value is an empty string:

```
var excelInfo = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelFileName);
var excelRecords = from c in excelInfo.Worksheet<myclass>(sheetname) where c.Result != null && c.Result != string.Empty select c;
```